# Drools how to make theorem prover using RETE?

Tags: drools

we need a system to prove theorem's like :

(A+B).(C+D) + E + C.(E+D) = A.C + A.D + B.C + B.D + E + C.E + C.D

these may be more complex

how to make a program for this using Drools ...

Tried making search tree using update modify methods but it was not working out somehow.

Comment: Are you serious? Do you want us to solve an academic and complex problem just in the meantime on SO? You haven't even specified the axioms of your formal system or any other details on how to manipulate its strings. how should anybody come up with a solution like that? Your question reads like: I have a complex problem here, I tried to solve it but somehow it didn't work. How do I do it? Pretty funny indeed...

Comment: could you please be a little more clear on what are you actually expecting, the question is not at all clear.

Answer (score 0):

As with any other Drools project:

1. Determine your requirements
2. Define your business rules in one short human readable simple sentence per rule
3. Determine what your facts will be
4. Implement in Drools